# How to prove that the reversal of the concatenation of two strings is the concatenation of the reversals?

Tags: formal-languages, proof-techniques, induction

Given languages $L_1$ and $L_2$, how do we prove that
$$(L_1L_2)^{\mathrm{rev}} = (L_2^{\mathrm{rev}})(L_1^{\mathrm{rev}})\,,$$
where ${}^{\mathrm{rev}}$ denotes reversal?

I think using mathematical induction, it can be shown true for two languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ of length $1$ each and then do induction using one of the lengths and then repeat with the other length. 
Is there any other way of proving this in a simpler way without making it too big with induction method?

Answer (score 5):

Well, consider the following "proof" (I'll explain afterwords why the quotation marks):

Let $w=a_1\cdots a_n$ be a word, then we have that

$w\in (L_1L_2)^{\mathrm{rev}}$ iff

$a_n\cdots a_1\in L_1L_2$, iff

there exists $0\le k\le n$ such that $a_n\cdots a_k\in L_1$ and $a_{k-1}\cdots a_1\in L_2$, iff

there exists $0\le k\le n$ such that $a_k\cdots a_n\in L_1^{\mathrm{rev}}$ and $a_{1}\cdots a_
{k-1}\in L_2^{\mathrm{rev}}$, iff

$a_1\cdots a_n\in L_2^{\mathrm{rev}}L_1^{\mathrm{rev}}$ iff

$w\in L_2^{\mathrm{rev}}L_1^{\mathrm{rev}}$

In my opinion, this proof is correct, formal, and would be accepted as a proof of the claim.

However, each "iff" along the way (apart from the last one) actually hides an inductive proof. The point is that each of these inductions is extremely trivial.
In fact, even writing $w=a_1\cdots a_n$ actually hides some induction. So you need to ask yourself how "deep" do you want to go into the technicalities.

If you want to prove this claim from basic principles, i.e. from the axioms of set theory, then you need to formalize everything. This would be very painful, but such things are actually useful when we use computer-assisted proofs.

Comment: "However, each "iff" along the way (apart from the last one) actually hides an inductive proof." -- I'm a stickler for rigor, but I don't see it here. What would you want to perform induction over? The way I see it, the proof goes through for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: Well, for example, the (formal) definition of the reverse operation is inductive. That is, $\sigma'=\sigma$, and $(w\sigma)'=\sigma w'$. Now we can define the reverse of a language, but the claim $a_1\cdots a_n\in L$ iff $a_n\cdots a_1\in L'$ still needs to be proved by induction over $n$. But perhaps I was indeed exaggerating - the second and fourth "iff" are by definition of concatenation, and not by induction.

Comment: @Shaull You could choose an inductive definition of reversal but why would you want to? I'd much rather choose to define the reversal of $a_1\dots a_k$ to be $a_k\dots a_1$ and be done with it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Right, but the definition of $a_1\cdots a_k$ as a word, or as an $n$-tuple, is inductive on $n$. That is, a Cartesian product of length $n$ is defined by induction on $n$, so you're just pushing the induction to a lower level.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. If we implemented this in an interactive theorem prover, this is indeed what we'd have to do. The high-level perspective we take with "$\dots$" is not available there. Outside of such systems, however, I don't think we usually define reversal inductively, hence an inductive proof would only confuse. Thanks for clarifying! (cc @DavidRicherby)

Comment: @Shaull You could choose an inductive definition of words but why would you want to? I'd much rather choose to define a word as being a sequence of characters from some alphabet and be done with it. Unless you're actually _studying_ the foundations of mathematics, we are the masters of the definitions, not the other way around. We choose the definitions that make our lives easiest. At some point, we must choose our "fundamental" objects and I'd much rather just say that sequences are fundamental than insist that sequences be formed by a pairing operation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - I think @ Raphael made my point pretty clear. We indeed don't use such inductions, because we have a common understanding of "$\cdots$", and it could indeed be a formal object. It's just that in ZFC, or such axiom systems, it usually isn't. Since formal languages are used in e.g. theorem provers, I think it isn't harmful to raise the point that it could be proved using induction. But I see your point, and I agree that the easier definitions should be chosen.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't see how to define $\Sigma^*$ or even $\mathbb{N}$ in a non-inductive way, if we wanted to really go down to the most rigorous level. For instance, Flajolet et al. define their SEQ operator by (the smallest fixpoint of) SEQ(A) = A ⋅ SEQ(A) + ε.

Comment: "I'd much rather just say that sequences are fundamental than insist that sequences be formed by a pairing operation." -- That's of course possible, in principle, but I don't think I've ever seen it *truly* done. Sequences are usually defined as member of a set that you get by applying an operator (the Kleene star) on a set (the alphabet).

Comment: Besides, we often *do* use the inductive nature of words, e.g. when we prove correctness of automata and such.

Comment: I would even avoid splitting the string into its letters. Observing that for two words $w_1\in L_1$ and  $w_2\in L_2$ we have $(w_1w_2)^{rev} = w_2^{rev} w_1^{rev}$ should be enough?

Answer (score 2):

I know that we already have an solution to this problem,
but the above solution's comments inspired me to write
this presentation.

The sequences over a type `X` are *defined* to be the
free monoid over `X`.
In particular, this means we have a monoid `List X`
with a binary operation denoted `_++_`, unit denoted `[]`,
and singelton embedding `x ↦ [x]`.
─this is the common notation in the functional programming community.

Since every element of this monoid ─ie every sequence─ is either
empty, a singelton, or a catenation, we can define the reverse
inductively by

```
_ʳᵉᵛ : List X → List X
[]ʳᵉᵛ = []
[x]ʳᵉᵛ = [x]
(u ++ v)ʳᵉᵛ = v ʳᵉᵛ ++ u ʳᵉᵛ
```

Then we can calculate the desideratum as follows:

```
   (L₁ · L₂)ʳᵉᵛ
=⟨ direct image definition ⟩
   { (u ++ v)ʳᵉᵛ ❙ u ∈ L₁ ∧ v ∈ L₂}
=⟨ definition of _ʳᵉᵛ ⟩
   { v ʳᵉᵛ ++ u ʳᵉᵛ ❙ u ∈ L₁ ∧ v ∈ L₂}
=⟨ dummy renaming ⟩
   { v ʳᵉᵛ ʳᵉᵛ ++ u ʳᵉᵛ ʳᵉᵛ ❙ u ʳᵉᵛ ∈ L₁ ∧ v ʳᵉᵛ ∈ L₂ }
=⟨ ʳᵉᵛ is an involution as can be easily checked ⟩
   { v ++ u ❙ u ʳᵉᵛ ∈ L₁ ∧ v ʳᵉᵛ ∈ L₂ }
=⟨ direct image definition ⟩
   { v ++ u ❙ u ∈ L₁ ʳᵉᵛ ∧ v ∈ L₂ ʳᵉᵛ }
=⟨ symmetry of conjunction ⟩
   { v ++ u ❙ v ∈ L₂ ʳᵉᵛ ∧ u ∈ L₁ ʳᵉᵛ }
=⟨ definition of language catenation ⟩
   L₂ ʳᵉᵛ · L₁ ʳᵉᵛ
```

I just wanted to mention this alternative view of sequences :-)