# How to prove that a string is made up of subsequences occurring some arbitrary number of times using concatenation?

Tags: formal-languages, proof-techniques, induction

How to prove that a string, `s` is made up of `n > 1` subsequences occurring some arbitrary number of times using concatenation and stripping first and last character?
 E.g `s = xyzxyz`, subsequence is `xyz` and it occurs 2 times. The solution is to concatenate the same string e.g. `xyzxyzxyzxyz` and then strip the first and last character to get `yzxyzxyzxy`, then you find `s` (`xyzxyz`) inside that.

Other examples:

1. The word `Table` does not have a subsequence so the above method will give:
   `Table||Table` -> `TableTable` -> `ableTabl` -> which does not contain
   Table so Table does not contain a subsequence
2. The word `mmebmmebmmeb` -> has to return true with the above method because it contains `mmeb` repeated 3 times. So, `mmebmmebmmeb || mmebmmebmmeb` -> `mmebmmebmmebmmebmmebmmeb` -> (strip first and last) `mebmmebmmebmmebmmebmme` which contains `mmebmmebmmeb` (`meb**mmebmmebmmeb**mmebmme`)

My thought was to assume that there is at least one character in `s` that will invalidate the occurrence of a subsequence. E.g. instead of `xyzxyzxyz` (`xyz` occurring three times) we have `xyzxyzxya` where `a` is the wrong char. Now we assume that in   `yzxyzxyaxyzxyzxy` (after concatenation and stripping first and last) that the string `s` does exist which should be a contradiction - but I am stuck.

Could someone give me a formal mathematical proof?

Looked at this for ideas:
[How to prove that the reversal of the concatenation of two strings is the concatenation of the reversals?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/62843/how-to-prove-that-the-reversal-of-the-concatenation-of-two-strings-is-the-concat?newreg=0a8184506ded4092bbcb71fdf91e073b)

Comment: I don't understand your question. If we're allowed $n=1$, it's trivial: the string `MattIsGreat` is one copy of `xMattIsGreatx` with the first and last character removed. If we're not allowed $n=1$, then the thing you're trying to prove is false, since `MattIsGreat` can't be written as two or more copies of anything.

Comment: Yes, I changed to n > 1. You are right MattIsGreat does not have a subsequence that's why the method above returns false. If we have MattMatt then the above method returns true MattMattMattMatt => attMattMattMat and MattMatt is present

Comment: OK (and I see that, actually, you had that case covered in your examples). But I'm still not sure what you're trying to prove. Your first sentence is, basically, "How can I prove this thing that isn't true for all strings?", to which the answer is "You can't, unless you restrict the choice of strings, because it's not true for a general string $s$." So what is it that you want a proof of?

Comment: If there exists a string, s which can be formed using repeated subsequences what is the mathematical proof showing that concatenation and stripping first and last characters returns true if the string was made up of the subsequence, otherwise false

Comment: OK, I see where you're going. You've described an algorithm to solve the problem "Does this string have property X?" and you're trying to prove that the algorithm is correct. I was trying to edit to hopefully clarify that, but then I realised that your solution to the first example, $xyzxyz$, makes the problem trivial again. Every nonempty string $s$ is a substring of $sss$ with the first and last characters removed. For example, `MattIsGreat` is a substring of `attIsGreatMattIsGreatMattIsGrea`. I thought you wanted $s$ to _be_ $t^n$ minus the first and last chars, not just a substring of it.

Comment: this problem is almost trivial. i guess you want to say for a string `repeat(n, s)`, where `s` is the substring and `n` is the number of repeats. then concatenation means `repeat(n + n, s)`, and removing two chars generates `repeat(n + n - 2, s)`. you want to show `forall n, n > 1 -> 2 * n - 2 >= n`? it's triviality.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr We are interested in the other direction, which is less trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first state the theorem that we are trying to prove.

**Theorem.** Let $w \neq \epsilon$ be a word. Then $w^2 = xwy$ for $x,y \neq \epsilon$ if and only if $w = z^p$ for some $p > 1$.

**Proof.** Let us first suppose that $w = z^p$ for some $p > 1$. Then $w^2 = z^{2p} = zwz^{p-1}$, where $z,z^{p-1} \neq \epsilon$.

In the other direction, write $w = w_1w_2$, where $|xw_1| = |w_2y| = |w|$. Since $x,y \neq \epsilon$, we see that $|w_1|,|w_2| < |w|$. We have $ww = xw_1w_2y$ implies that $w = xw_1 = w_2y$, and so $x = w_2$ (since $|x| = |w|-|w_1| = |w_2|$). In other words, $w = w_2w_1$.

Now let $w = \sigma_0 \ldots \sigma_{n-1}$, and let $|w_2| = m$. Note that since $|w_1|,|w_2| < n$, we have $0 < m < n$. The equality $w = w_2w_1$ implies (check!) that $\sigma_i = \sigma_{i+m \bmod{n}}$. Let $g$ be the GCD of $m$ and $n$; note that $g < n$. It is known that $g = am + bn$ for some integers $a,b$, and so $\sigma_i = \sigma_{i+bm \bmod{n}} = \sigma_{i+g \bmod{n}}$. Since $g \mid n$, this implies that $w = (\sigma_1 \ldots \sigma_g)^{n/g}$, where $n/g > 1$.